# How do I fix the part in __str__ so it would display the name of the instance within the class? Python 2X

Tags: python-2.7, class

How do I change the code so that it would return **a is a square with side:5 and area:25 ??** when I call print a?

```
    class Square():
        def __init__(self, length):
            self.length = length
        def area(self):
            return self.length ** 2
        def __str__(self): #this is the part I don't know how to write
            return "is a square with side:%s and area:%s." % (self.length, self.area())
    a = Square(5)
    print a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to get the name of the variable that you asign with your class, right??

I don't know how to do that or is that is posible (or usefull in any way) because you can have have multiples variables pointing to the same object 
for example in this

```
a=SomeObject()
b=a
c=a
d=c
```

and in this case how you will know which one you are using if all of them point to the same object?

A alternative is give your class a extra paremetrer with the name that you wish for you instance

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self, length,name=""):
        self.length = length
        self.name = name  
    def area(self):
        return self.length ** 2
    def __str__(self): #this is the part I don't know how to write
        return "%s is a square with side:%s and area:%s." % (self.name, self.length, self.area())
a = Square(5,'MySquare') 
print a # MySquare is a square with side:5 and area:25.
```

Comment: I'd like to be return the variable of the same instance.
e.g.  a = Square(1), b = Square(2)
when print a is called it would return **bold a is a square with side:1 and area:1**
when print b is called it would return **bold b is a square with side:2 and area:4**
I don't understand why it would be impossible to refer to the same instance.  isn't it as straight forward as calling the self argument??

Comment: if you want bold letters then you need a GUI for that, or html, or something else that give you that options.

Comment: any object only know about its internal definitions and atributes, and the name of any variable that point to it is outside of that, so you can look at the instance all day long but you will not found it. You need to give a name to that instance like in my example

Comment: I read in someone's comment that Python is does not have true varaiables.  Is that refer to what you mean in your reply?  that a variable of the instance is simply a reference to an object therefore calling the variable of the instance.  either way, I think your solution works at the end.  thanks

Comment: what do you mean by true variable?

Comment: some recommended lectures about it: [Facts and myths about Python names and value](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), [Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither.](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/), [Is Python pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)